# C#/VB.net and click on javascript don't work

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, joomla

I have this  :

```
<div id="comments-form-buttons">
<div class="btn" id="comments-form-send"><div><a href="#" tabindex="7" onclick="jcomments.saveComment();return false;" title="Enregistrer (ctrl+entrée)">Enregistrer</a></div></div>
<div class="btn" id="comments-form-cancel" style="display: none;"><div><a href="#" tabindex="8" onclick="return false;" title="Annuler">Annuler</a></div></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

And i would to click on send button.
I have try this

```
submit.Document.GetElementById("jcomments-form-send").InvokeMember("click")
```

but it doesn't work.
Can you help me ?
Have a nice day.

Comment: Shouldn't the id you are sending to `GetElementById` be `comments-form-send` instead of `jcomments-form-send`? That may be the problem.

Comment: No, i have test it's don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Oaybi,   here in the JS  u are using the samething i Said in last answer.
 U are using a Class `('myDivClass')`  in the JavaScript to get the elemente `getElementsByClassName`!

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('myDivClass')[0].click();void(0);"); //assuming it's first and/or only div with that class


<div id="comments-form-buttons">
<div class="btn" id="comments-form-send"><div><a href="#" tabindex="7" onclick="jcomments.saveComment();return false;" title="Enregistrer(ctrl+entrée)">Enregistrer</a></div></div>
<div class="btn" id="comments-form-cancel" style="display: none;"><div><a href="#" tabindex="8" onclick="return false;" title="Annuler">Annuler</a></div></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Do that in your code:

CODE:
     
        
              //should be the uniq this class name in this case!!
                 Enregistrer
              
        
        
               
                    Annuler

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('_MyDiv_Test1')[0].click();void(0);");
```

In this case, u get  the DIV BY THE CSS CLASS. Just like i said last answer.

try this and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Please mark the answer  as Useful !    u r welcome, call me if u need something!  hugs

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CssClass to get the element(div) and access it in the JS! Remember this CssClass should be unique

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div id="comments-form-buttons">
<div class="BTN" id="comments-form-send"><div><a href="#BTN" tabindex="7" onclick="jcomments.saveComment();return false;" title="Enregistrer (ctrl+entrée)">Enregistrer</a></div></div>
<div class="btn" id="comments-form-cancel" style="display: none;"><div><a href="#" tabindex="8" onclick="return false;" title="Annuler">Annuler</a></div></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".BTN").click(function(e) { // do some thing here });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Hav you this code in vb.net ? http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ don't work. Thanks

Comment: @Oyabi sorry,I dont. I dont work with VB..  can u add a button  instead this <a> ?

Comment: U can  ADD a class in  the <a> ?  if u can   create like this  <a href="#BTN" tabindex="7" onclick="jcomments.saveComment();return false;" title="Enregistrer (ctrl+entrée)" class="Test_1">

Then  in the Script  change the name   $(".BTN").click(function(e)  to $(".Test_1").click(function(e)....


You can get a Click  using a CssClass  in JS

Comment: @Oyabi Also , delete the onclick="jcomments.saveComment();return false;"  them ADD the Class="Test_1" and in the Script  Call $(".Teste_1").click   -   It should work fine! Tell me if don't work!!

Comment: I can't modify html/css/php/javascript.

Comment: @Oyabi that's hard... if u cant modify any part, how can u fix it?  sorry  i dont know anything else to try to help u :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found this

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('myDivClass')[0].click();void(0);"); //assuming it's first and/or only div with that class
```

But i don't know javascript, somebody can translate for me please ?
My div :

```
<div id="comments-form-buttons">
<div class="btn" id="comments-form-send"><div><a href="#" tabindex="7" onclick="jcomments.saveComment();return false;" title="Enregistrer(ctrl+entrée)">Enregistrer</a></div></div>
<div class="btn" id="comments-form-cancel" style="display: none;"><div><a href="#" tabindex="8" onclick="return false;" title="Annuler">Annuler</a></div></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Thank you and have a nice day.